# What is the different between @ManyToOne optional flag vs @JoinColumn nullable flag?

Tags: jpa

I have the following to define a Company which cannot be null on my entity:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private Company company;
```

What is the difference between 'optional = false' on the @ManyToOne annotation and 'nullable = false' on the @JoinColumn annotation.  Or is setting both of them redundant?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`@ManyToOne` operates on the so called logical model, i.e. the object-oriented side of the object-relational mapping. The semantics of `optional=false` here are:

> Whether the association is optional. If set to false then a non-null relationship must always exist.

So the JPA engine expects that the underlying storage will always provide a value that can be translated to a `Company` object.

`@JoinColumn` operates on the physical model, i.e. how things are actually laid down in the datastore (database). Specifying `nullable = false` will make the DB column non-nullable.

If `@JoinColumn(nullable = false)` was omitted, the column would be nullable. One could insert a null value there and the *DB* would happily accept it. However if someone tried to read that value through JPA, the *JPA engine* would protest because it expects a value that can be translated to a `Company` object to always be there, as specified by `@ManyToOne(optional = false)`.

Comment: So, what are the practical use-cases for setting different values for `ManyToOne::optional` and `JoinColumn::nullable`?

Comment: There is a discussion [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8229). It's seems difficult to find a good practical use-case for that! @Sasha